# Нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу

Tags: ассемблер

При выполнении ассемблерной вставки на последнем printf вылазит нарушение прав доступа, хотя результат считает правильно

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    short int a[N];
    short int c = 0, d = 0 , k=1;
    printf("c<=a[i]<=d\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Enter the values of the range [-32768...32767]:\n");
        printf("c = "); scanf_s("%hd", &c);
        printf("d = "); scanf_s("%hd", &d);
        if (c >= d)
        {
            printf("c can not be greater or equal d! Enter values again.\n\n");
        }
    } while (c >= d);
    int n = N;
    short int res = 1, resC = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 10;
        printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
        if (c <= a[i] && a[i] <= d) resC *= a[i];
    }
    printf("Result C++ = %d\n", resC);
    __asm
    {
        mov di, c // <di>=c
        mov bx, d //<bx>=d
        mov ecx, n //<ecn>=n
        dec ecx //<ecn>=n-1
        mov sp,1 
        mov ax, sp;
        cycle : 
        shl ecx, 1 // зсув вліво на 1 розряд


            mov si, a[ecx] //<si>= a[ecx]
            cmp si, 0 // порівнюємо значення регістра <si> з 0
            jl exit1 // якщо менше - перейти до циклу exit1
        cmp si, di // порівнюємо значення регістра <si> з значенням в регістрі <di>
            jl exit1 // якщо менше - перейти до циклу exit1
        cmp si, bx // порівнюємо значення регістра <si> з значенням в регістрі <bx>
            jg exit1 // якщо більше - перейти до циклу exit1

            imul si
            idiv sp


            exit1 : 
        shr ecx, 1 // зсув вправо на 1 розряд
            dec ecx // зменшуємо значення в регістрі <ecx> на 1
            cmp ecx, 0 // порівнюємо значення регістра <ecx> з 0
            jnl cycle // поки не менше - перейти до циклу cycle

            mov res,ax


    }
    if (res > 32767 || res < -32768)
    {
        printf("Overflow!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Result ASM = %d\n", res);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Регистр SP - это указатель стека. вы разрушаете стек используя его. Никогда не используйте SP кроме случаев, когда вам действительно надо сделать что то нестандартное со стеком. Прочитайте для чего какие регистры принято использовать http://www.ccfit.nsu.ru/~kireev/lab2/lab2reg.htm

Comment: @Mike пробую использовать другие регистры - либо такая же ошибка, либо результат 1(не правльный)

Comment: После того как вы поправили SP, результат нельзя считать правильным, потому что printf может выводить совершенно не то, что на самом деле в переменных, он может выводить совершенно другую область памяти. Если он вдруг выводит то, что вы думали что посчитали, очень может быть, что это не то что было посчитано, а просто так совпало что вы видите ожидаемое значение

Comment: И вы в комментариях пишите не что делает команда, это и так всем известно, а то ради чего это делается. тогда может найдете какие нибудь ошибки в алгоритме и читающим ваш код может станет понятно что делает ваш код

Comment: @Mike Программа должна посчитать произведение элементов массива которые удовлетворяют условие c<=a[i]<=d.

Comment: И около самых интересных команд вы вообще не пишите что они делают и для чего. вот например зачем вы делаете `idiv sp` ? какой смысл делить число на 1 (а если вы вдруг в начале замените sp на другой регистр и забудете это сделать в середине, то вы поделите уже не на 1, а на что то другое и результат будет заведомо неверен)

Comment: Если вы считаете произведение элементов c<=a[i]<=d, то зачем вы сверяете a[i] с нулем и не умножаете отрицательные элементы, что если c отрицательно, вероятно отрицательные элементы так же должны войти ...

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил - сам ответил

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    short int a[N];
    short int c = 0, d = 0 , k=1;
    printf("c<=a[i]<=d\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Enter the values of the range [-32768...32767]:\n");
        printf("c = "); scanf_s("%hd", &c);
        printf("d = "); scanf_s("%hd", &d);
        if (c >= d)
        {
            printf("c can not be greater or equal d! Enter values again.\n\n");
        }
    } while (c >= d);
    int n = N;
    short int res = 1, resC = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 10;
        printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
        if (c <= a[i] && a[i] <= d) resC *= a[i];
    }
    printf("Result C++ = %d\n", resC);
    __asm
    {
        mov di, c // <di>=c
        mov bx, d //<bx>=d
        mov ecx, n //<ecn>=n
        dec ecx //<ecn>=n-1

        cycle : 
        shl ecx, 1 // зсув вліво на 1 розряд


            mov si, a[ecx] //<si>= a[ecx]
            cmp si, 0 // порівнюємо значення регістра <si> з 0
            jl exit1 // якщо менше - перейти до циклу exit1
        cmp si, di // порівнюємо значення регістра <si> з значенням в регістрі <di>
            jl exit1 // якщо менше - перейти до циклу exit1
        cmp si, bx // порівнюємо значення регістра <si> з значенням в регістрі <bx>
            jg exit1 // якщо більше - перейти до циклу exit1

            mov ax, res
            imul si
        mov res,ax

            exit1 : 
        shr ecx, 1 // зсув вправо на 1 розряд
            dec ecx // зменшуємо значення в регістрі <ecx> на 1
            cmp ecx, 0 // порівнюємо значення регістра <ecx> з 0
            jnl cycle // поки не менше - перейти до циклу cycle



    }
    if (res > 32767 || res < -32768)
    {
        printf("Overflow!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Result ASM = %d\n", res);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mike а он и решен) Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Я правда все равно не понимаю, зачем вы делаете `cmp si, 0` и переход после него. если зададут отрицательное значение `c` то результат будет неверным